# If $u$ is an isomorphism of $E$ into $F$, prove that to every $n$ there is $m$ such that $u^{-1}(F_n) \subset E_m$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $E$, $F$ be two LF-spaces (more details see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LF-space) or [here](http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/%7Einfusino/TVS-II/Lect3.pdf)), $\{E_m\}$, $\{F_n\}$ $(m, n = 1, 2 .... )$ two sequences of definition
of $E$ and $F$, respectively. If $u$ is an isomorphism of $E$ into $F$ (for the TVS structures), I want to prove that to every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$u^{-1}(F_n) \subset E_m.$$

I thought of the following: Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. So, $E_m \subset E$ and
$$u(E_m) \subset u(E) \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n,$$
what implies, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$u(E_m)=F_n \Rightarrow E_m=u^{-1}(F_n) \Rightarrow u^{-1}(F_n) \subset E_m.$$ I think this is wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: Your proof is wrong. Just because $u(E_m)\subseteq \bigcup_n F_n$ doesnt mean that $u(E_n)$ is contained in one of the sets over which you take the union.

Comment: @s.harp This claim is indeed true because of Grothendieck's factorization theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by an *isomorphism into*?

Comment: @Jochen Means that $u: E \longrightarrow F$ is continuous, one-to-one and $u^{-1}:u(E) \longrightarrow E$ is continuous.

Comment: @Jochen I don't know this theorem, and googling does not give something that looks useful here. Can you remark on its form?

Comment: The factorization theorem says that whenever you have a continuous linear map $T$ from a Fréchet space to a Hausdorff locally convex spce which is the union of a sequence of continuously embedded Fréchet spaces $E_n$ then the range of $T$ is contained in some $E_n$. This is certainly in the book *Introduction to Functional Analysis* of Meise and Vogt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem that you mean by LF-space a *strict* LF-space (à la Dieudonné-Schwartz, Grothendieck did not require strictness). Then $L=u(E)$ is complete (being isomorphic to $E$) and hence closed in $F$. Then
$F_n\cap L$ are closed in $F_n$. Then Grothendieck's factorization theorem for $u^{-1}: L\cap F_n\to E$ implies that $u^{-1}(F_n\cap L)$ is contained in some $E_m$ and this gives your claim because $u^{-1}(A)=u^{-1}(A\cap u(E))$ holds for every map $u:E\to F$ and every set $A$ in the range.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.